# non repeating th for each table row

Tags: python, html, flask

is there a way to remove the repeated th for each row?

I only want it to show at the top of the table, and not repeat for each row that I import from psql. I've searched and tried several options, but none seem to work for me. I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy to connect to a postgre table. (the table is called injection)

This is part of my code:

```
{% block contents %}
    <h1>Injection Data</h1>
    {% for inject in injection %}
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Cage Identifier</th>
            <th>Ear Notch Number</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Strain</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{inject.Timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Cage_Identifier}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Ear_Notch_Number}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.DOB}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Strain}}</td>

        </tr>    
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock contents %}
```

However, the column headers `th` will repeat for each row of data that is imported from the postgre table.

Comment: Please **remove** the picture of your code and replace it with your actual code, copy pasted into a Markdown code block (that is, 4-space indented).  Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: you're creating many tables, you should move the `for loop` just around the `<tr><td>` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<th>` and `<table>` must not be in loop only `<tr><td></td></tr>` needs to be in loop,
like below.

```
{% block contents %}
    <h1>Injection Data</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Cage Identifier</th>
            <th>Ear Notch Number</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Strain</th>
        </tr>
    {% for inject in injection %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{inject.Timestamp}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Cage_Identifier}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Ear_Notch_Number}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Age}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.DOB}}</td>
            <td>{{inject.Strain}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock contents %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried what you suggested, and only the first row becomes part of the table. The other rows just display as a bunch of text below. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Please check my code again or copy paste the same, may be `</table>` I had forgotten end table tag. Or share your code again by editing the question instead of image.

Comment: THANK YOU!! You are a genius. I had put the `</table>` before the tag. Thank you again.